# Problemas con @checked laravel 9

Tags: laravel, checkbox, radiobutton, laravel-9

tengo un problema intentando usar la nueva directiva de blade @checked en un from-check de dos inputs tipo radio. Cuando selecciono una opción y mando el formulario si mi Request retorna algun error de validacion me redirige con las entradas pero no selecciona el input radio seleccionado. dejo unas imagenes para explicar mejor:

[image: Selecciono una opción checkbox]

[image: Mi Request me regresa a mi formulario]

[image: Se selecciona la otra casilla y no la que elegí al principio y quiero que al regresarme la pagina se seleccione la opción que yo marque]

[image: Esa es la parte del codigo donde se encuentran los radio buttons]
Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Ponos alguna parte del codigo para que podamos ver o algo...

Comment: Listo, espero que con eso te puedas guiar o si necesitas mas estaré al pendiente

Answer (score 0):

[image: Resuelto !!]

Creo que con la direcctiva @checked no se puede trabajar un grupo de radio-button's pero de esta forma lo solucione

Comment: El código siempre _como texto, con formato_. Modifica tanto tu pregunta como tu respuesta: he aquí [por qué el código como imagen es mala idea](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976). No olvides además explicar tu respuesta: lee [answer].